# Is there a command in VS code for skipping a match when selecting words individually that match with ctrl+d?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, visual-studio-code

I have searched vscode's keyboard shortcuts but I can't seem to find a command.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Once you've started the matching using ctrl+d, you can press ctrl+k, ctrl+d to skip the current match. Use cmd+k, cmd+d on Mac.

Alternatively, to undo the most recent selection and go back one step, use ctrl+u (or cmd+u on Mac).